# Generics in return types of static methods and inheritance

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, static-methods

Generics in return types of static methods do not seem to get along well with inheritance. Please take a look at the following code:

```
class ClassInfo<C>  {
  public ClassInfo(Class<C> clazz) {
    this(clazz,null);
  }  
  public ClassInfo(Class<C> clazz, ClassInfo<? super C> superClassInfo) {
  }
}

class A {
    public static ClassInfo<A> getClassInfo() {
        return new ClassInfo<A>(A.class);
    }
}

class B extends A {
    // Error: The return type is incompatible with A.getClassInfo()
    public static ClassInfo<B> getClassInfo() { 
        return new ClassInfo<B>(B.class, A.getClassInfo());
    }
}
```

I tried to circumvent this by changing the return type for A.getClassInfo(), and now the error pops up at another location:

```
class ClassInfo<C>  {
  public ClassInfo(Class<C> clazz) {
    this(clazz,null);
  }  
  public ClassInfo(Class<C> clazz, ClassInfo<? super C> superClassInfo) {
  }
}

class A {
    public static ClassInfo<? extends A> getClassInfo() {
        return new ClassInfo<A>(A.class);
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public static ClassInfo<? extends B> getClassInfo() { 
        // Error: The constructor ClassInfo<B>(Class<B>, ClassInfo<capture#1-of ? extends A>) is undefined
        return new ClassInfo<B>(B.class, A.getClassInfo());
    }
}
```

What is the reason for this strict checking on static methods? And how can I get along? Changing the method name seems awkward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The static method in B does not override the static method in A but hides it. The [JLS 8.4.8.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3) explicitly says that the return types must be substitutable or it won't compile:

> If a method declaration d1 with return type R1 overrides or hides the declaration of another method d2 with return type R2, then d1 must be return-type-substitutable (§8.4.5) for d2, or a compile-time error occurs.

And substitutability is defined in JLS #8.4.5:

> A method declaration d1 with return type R1 is return-type-substitutable for another method d2 with return type R2, if and only if the following conditions hold:
>
> - [...]
> - If R1 is a reference type then:
>
>   - R1 is either a subtype of R2 or R1 can be converted to a subtype of R2 by unchecked conversion (§5.1.9), or
>   - R1 = |R2|

In your case: d1 is the method in B, R1 is `ClassInfo<B>`, d2 the method in A and R2 is `ClassInfo<A>`. And `ClassInfo<B>` is not a subtype of `ClassInfo<A>`.

However, `ClassInfo<? extends B>` can be converted to `ClassInfo<? extends A>`. You can observe that behaviour in:

```
void someMethod(){
    ClassInfo<B> b1 = (ClassInfo<B>) get1(); //does not compile
    ClassInfo<? extends B> b2 = (ClassInfo<? extends B>) get2(); //compiles
}

ClassInfo<A> get1() {
    return null;
}

ClassInfo<? extends A> get2() {
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't override a static method. So when you declare the same static method, you are creating a new method.

```
public static ClassInfo<B> getClassInfo() { 
    return new ClassInfo<B>(B.class, A.getClassInfo());
}
```

But, when you declare your method with changed return type, it is **not a valid method hiding**, **neither an override**. So, both the `getClassInfo()` method of `class A` and `getClassInfo()` method of `class B`, conflict each other. As the method of class A is also visible in class B.

So, in other words, `class B` has same method, as it has inherited from `class A`, with change in return type. And since return type of method is not considered a part of method signature. Hence the conflict.

So, you need to have exactly same return type. In which case, class B will ignore the inherited method, and use its own.

Comment: But why is the declaration in my second example working? The error I get is from Invoking the `ClassInfo<B>` constructor and it works if I change it to `return new ClassInfo<B>(B.class, (ClassInfo<? super B>) A.getClassInfo());`.

Comment: Because `? extends A` also covers class B. And `? super B` too covers class B. So, it works.